# Ranking customers by orders per customer and items per order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to rank a query by not just one count, but by two.

I want to rank customers by the order items per orders.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        o.CustomerId,
        COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) AS OrderCount, 
        COUNT(oi.OrderItemId) AS OrderItemCount
    FROM 
        OrderItem oi
    INNER JOIN 
        Order o ON o.OrderId = oi.OrderId
    WHERE 
        o.CategoryId = 52 -- website sales
    GROUP BY 
        o.CustomerId
)
SELECT 
    cust.Code, 
    cust.DisplayTitle,
    CTE.OrderCount,
    CTE.OrderItemCount,
    --AVG(CTE.OrderItemCount/CTE.OrderCount) AS SumProduct ????
FROM 
    CTE
INNER JOIN 
    Customer cust ON cust.CustomerId = CTE.CustomerId
GROUP BY 
    cust.Code, 
    cust.DisplayTitle,
    CTE.OrderCount,
    CTE.OrderItemCount
ORDER BY 
    SumProduct DESC
```

I'm basically trying to implement the T-SQL equivalent of `SUMPRODUCT()` in Excel.

Comment: _"I've got this far"_ What does that do, why is that wrong, and what output do you need instead? Example input and output data would help a lot too.

Comment: @underscore_d It's the bit with '????'. I want to rank customers by  order items per order. I'm trying to implement the equivalent of SUMPRODUCT in Excel in TSQL.

Comment: Not sure why you want sumproduct... this sounds like you would just use an OLAP ranking function, most likely ROW_NUMBER() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    o.CustomerId,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) AS OrderCount, 
    COUNT(oi.OrderItemId) AS OrderItemCount,
    COUNT(oi.OrderItemId) / COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) avg 
FROM OrderItem oi
INNER JOIN Order o ON o.OrderId = oi.OrderId
WHERE o.CategoryId = 52 -- website sales
GROUP BY o.CustomerId 
order by COUNT(oi.OrderItemId) / COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderId) desc
```

Just add in the join to customer

Comment: Thanks. You got what I was trying to badly explain! :)